# Skipping for loop in python csv.reader, for row in

Tags: python

I was a little curious because when I add a single line in my code, that counts the number of rows in the csv file, the for loop is stop working and just skipping everything inside.

My code shown below, is working now, but if I uncomment the row_count it's not working, so my question is why?

```
with open(r"C:\Users\heltbork\Desktop\test\ICM.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    sensor = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

    #row_count = sum(1 for row in sensor)
    #print(row_count)
    for row in sensor:
        #alot of stuff here
```

Comment: When you do a 'sum(1 for row in sensor)' the file would have been read completely and when you try to do the same again, it would be empty.

Comment: You can try like `len(list(sensor))`

Comment: why are you using `sum` i.e a python builtin function as a variable . I think that is causing the issue. Please using some other name for counting

Comment: @toheedNiaz it's indeed the builtin, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reader is an iterable (see the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)):

> ... One notable exception is code which attempts multiple iteration passes. A container object (such as a list) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it to the iter() function or use it in a for loop. Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty container.

The iterable is consumed when you iterate it. It is not a concrete data structure:

```
sensor = csv.reader(...) # creates an iterator

row_count = sum(1 for row in sensor) # *consumes* the iterator

for row in sensor: # nothing in the iterator, consumed by `sum`
    # a lot of stuff here
```

You should count while you iterate (inside `for row in sensor:`), because once you iterate and consume it - you can't iterate again.

Alternatives are using `list` for concreting the data, or if you need the iterable interface - `itertools.tee` (if you don't have a lot if data). You can also use `enumerate` and keep the last index.

Example:

```
sensor = csv.reader(...) # creates an iterator

count = 0
for idx, row in enumerate(sensor):
    # a lot of stuff here
    # ...
    count = idx
print(count)
```

Or:

```
count = 0
for row in sensor:
    # a lot of stuff here
    # ...
    count += 1
print(count)
```